# serialize json data from nhibernate

Tags: ajax, json, nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate

I know there are a couple threads on this but none of them have solved my issue.  I'm trying to pull data from a ms sql db via Fluent nHibernate and serialize it to json data to the front end.  Here is my nHibernate code:

```
[WebMethod]
[ScriptMethod(ResponseFormat = ResponseFormat.Json)]
public string GetClans()
{
    string output = string.Empty;

    IList<Clan> clans = Counter.Strike.Database.Clan.GetAllClans();

    Clan[] clanJson = new Clan[clans.Count];

    for (int i = 0; i < clans.Count; i++ )
    {
        clanJson[i] = new Clan();
        clanJson[i].Clan_Id = clans[i].Clan_Id;
        clanJson[i].Clan_Name = clans[i].Clan_Name;
    }

    output = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(clanJson);
    return output;
}
```

I'm using the same concept as found here: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/45275/Create-a-JSON-WebService-in-ASP-NET-with-a-jQu
The Clan table has a circular reference to the Users table so that's why I am creating a temp object to serialize.  My JSON data looks like this:

```
[
    {
        "Clan_Id": 1,
        "Clan_Name": "Dog LB",
        "Owner": null,
        "DateRegistered": "0001-01-01T00:00:00"
    },
    {
        "Clan_Id": 2,
        "Clan_Name": "Frazzes",
        "Owner": null,
        "DateRegistered": "0001-01-01T00:00:00"
    },
    {
        "Clan_Id": 3,
        "Clan_Name": "Goobers",
        "Owner": null,
        "DateRegistered": "0001-01-01T00:00:00"
    },
    {
        "Clan_Id": 4,
        "Clan_Name": "DooGooers",
        "Owner": null,
        "DateRegistered": "0001-01-01T00:00:00"
    }
]
```

And finally here is my AJAX call:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src='<%=Page.ResolveUrl("~/Scripts/jquery-2.1.1.min.js") %>'>     </script>

<script>
window.onload = function () {
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "http://localhost:8379/Services/CounterStrike.asmx/GetClans",
        data: "{}",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (msg) {
            $.each(msg.d, function (index, elem) {
                alert(index + ":" + elem);
            });
        },
        error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError)
        { alert(xhr.status); alert(thrownError); }
    });
}
</script>
```

My HTML:

```
<p>
   <b>Choose a Clan:</b>
   <select id="clans">
      <option value="-1">-- Select a Clan --</option>
   </select>
</p>
<div id="users"></div>
```

On page load, i'm making an ajax call to the db to poll the list of clans which is serialized to json and populates the drop down list.  Unfortunately, I do not get a popup of each clan.  Instead, I check the javascript console and see:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot use 'in' operator to search for '353' in
>   [{"Clan_Id":1,"Clan_Name":"Dog
>   LB","Owner":null,"DateRegistered":"0001-01-01T00:00:00"},{"Clan_Id":2,"Clan_Name":"Frazzes","Owner":null,"DateRegistered":"0001-01-01T00:00:00"},{"Clan_Id":3,"Clan_Name":"Goobers","Owner":null,"DateRegistered":"0001-01-01T00:00:00"},{"Clan_Id":4,"Clan_Name":"DooGooers","Owner":null,"DateRegistered":"0001-01-01T00:00:00"}]

Any ideas?  Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ah ha! Success.  After two days of digging, I found that all i needed was to add an eval to my response data:

```
success: function (msg) {
        $.each(eval(msg.d), function (index, elem) {
            alert(index + ":" + elem);
        });
    },
```

and everything worked!